# Elasticsearch - get terms aggregation for specified fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using terms aggregations to get all the no of users from each city

```
{
"aggs" : {
"cities" : {
    "terms" : { "field" : "city.name" }
    }
  }
}
```

This is giving results. But I always want to get some specific cities in results of aggregation irrespective of whether they are in top 10 or not. Do I need to  use filter aggregation for each of the city separately to get its result?

Comment: You could probably just create a custom sort with groovy/painless scripting, however I would go with creating two seperate aggregations and merging them in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three solutions:

A. You can specify a filter in the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "city.name": [ "city1", "city2", "city3" ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "cities": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "city.name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

B. You can specify a filter in the aggregations:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "city_filter": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "city.name": [
            "city1",
            "city2",
            "city3"
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "cities": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "city.name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

C. You can [filter values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_2) in the terms aggregation:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "cities": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "city.name",
        "include": "city1*",
        "exclude": "city2*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```